# lxml iterate through child divs

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I have the below html code where i parse ratings/text etc.
How can I iterate through all divs class contain "posting item" below the div "wrap" using lxml and tree?

With the below I get all post divs selected at the same time,

```
forumposts = tree.xpath("//div[@class='wrap']//div[contains(@class, 'posting item')]")

# here i want to iterate through posting items 
# so i should have 1 text/rating to process in the parse function
for post in forumposts:
   parse(post)
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="posting item theme-international" data-postingid="1035091361">
    <div class="thread">
        <div class="js-ratings ratings">
            <div class="js-ratings-counts ratings-counts" data-closable- 
    target="ratinglog-1-1035091361" 
onclick="ForumLoader.toggleRatinglog(1035091361, 1)">
<span class="js-ratings-negative-count ratings-negative-
count">6</span>
<span class="js-ratings-positive-count ratings-positive-
count">7</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <a href="xyz" rel="nofollow">
                <strong/>
                <span>Posting text 1 </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="posting item theme-international" data-postingid="1035091361">
    <div class="thread">
        <div class="js-ratings ratings">
            <div class="js-ratings-counts ratings-counts" data-closable-
target="ratinglog-1-1035091361" 
onclick="ForumLoader.toggleRatinglog(1035091361, 
1)">
                <span class="js-ratings-negative-count ratings-negative-
count">1</span>
                <span class="js-ratings-positive-count ratings-positive- 
count">11</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <a href="xyz" rel="nofollow">
                <strong/>
                <span>Posting text 2</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you want, Nico. Is it this?

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree = etree.parse(open('nico.htm'), parser)
>>> for s in tree.xpath('//div[@class="wrap"]//div[@class="text"]//span'):
...     s.text
...     
'Posting text 1 '
'Posting text 2'
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that out, it looks promising.

Comment: @NicoMüller: Welcome! As you may discern, it works on your example html. If not on the actual html let me know.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I didn't get to it yet, I will mark as answered or come back to you ASAP. Thanks